# Create new files from existing ones but change their extension

Tags: shell, terminal

In shell, what is a good way to duplicating files in an existing directory so that the result gives the same file but with a different extension? So taking something like:

```
path/view/blah.html.erb
```

And adding:

```
path/view/blah.mobile.erb
```

So that in the `path/view` directory, there would be:

```
path/view/blah.html.erb
path/view/blah.mobile.erb
```

I'd ideally like to perform this at a directory level and not create the file if it already has both extensions but that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
cd /path/view/

for f in *.html.erb; do
   cp "$f" "${f/.html./.mobile.}"
done
```

**PS:** This replaces first instance of `.html.` with `.mobile.`, syntax is `bash specific` (let me know if you're not using BASH).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this is `bash`-specific and that it replaces the *first* occurrence of `.html` if the string appears multiple times in the file name (e.g., `foo.html-template.html.erb`).

Comment: Also, the `.` does not need to be escaped in the parameter expansion, as it has no special meaning in a glob pattern.

Comment: @chepner: Yes you are right, somehow my regex habits creep into glob also. Fixed it now.

Comment: @tvalent2, combine this with a file existence test: `[[ -f "$filename" ]]` and you're set.